# Recently, I have about 10 new orders that have an id and orderid but can't find them in the sales order grid

Tags: orders, magento2.2.6, order-status, increment-id

I have the time of **checkout** and the amount as well as `shipping_first_name` and `shipping_last_name`. The thing is the status is abandoned and the response is "failed" like their CC didn't process correctly. Why would magento create an **increment id** if the transaction didn't go through? I've looked in admin and can't find anything. Additionally, i've looked in the `sales_order` table to no avail. Is there another table that stores this information, failed sales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when a customer starts to choose and pick product items and put them on the cart, orders data are saved in **`quote`** table.

Now, regardless if the customer will place the order or not, or the order was not processed because of the failed payment transaction the same as you mentioned or the customer suddenly just abandoned the webshop and did not proceed with the checkout process, the data will remain saved in the **quote** table. That is for the purpose that whenever the customer wants to go back to the webshop and try to order again, his data will just be retrieved and there's no need for him to redo the ordering process. And that's the reason also that you will not see that order in your sales order list since they are not yet considered as an order(because they are still in quote). So to say, orders in the admin orders list are placed orders.

In your case, to verify this, you can check the **`quote`** table to see if the entries that you are looking are there.

Lastly, **`increment_id`** is created in **`quote`** table in column **`reserved_order_id`**. They are only assigned as **`increment_id`** in the **`sales_order`** table once the checkout process is done.